# How would I make a messageBox not show within a time limit of a button click? c#

Tags: c#, time, limit

I am making a save system in my program, and I wanted to make it where if you have not saved a log within 1 minute it will appear a messagebox. In other words I want the messageBox not show if you clicked a button within 1 minute. How would I go about doing this?

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            DialogResult choice = MessageBox.Show("          Would you like to save the Log?", "Save Log?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            if (choice == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                button6.PerformClick();
                e.Cancel = false;
            }

            else if (choice == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What irreparable harm is done if you just save it without asking?

Comment: Use something like a `System.Threading.Timer` and invoke the message box on timeout, you can cancel the timer if they click on save.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the window from the log save is still open. Next you can create a thread with Thread.sleep(miliseconds) and show, after the delay has passed the message box. You can create a function on window exit so that it will also activate the message box when the log window is closed within one min.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void CreateTimer()
 {
     static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
     myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

      // Sets the timer interval to 1 minute.
      myTimer.Interval = 60000;
      myTimer.Start();
 }

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                        EventArgs myEventArgs) {
   myTimer.Stop();

   // Write code here to show the message box asking the user to save
   // Once the user has saved restart the timer
   myTimer.Start();


}
```

Remember when the user saves you need to stop and start the timer. Write that code in your save method.